# remove the same value in queryString in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove the same value queryString when searching for `ID` in jQuery, `ID` is being pass in `textarea` and calls an API when searching. When searching for similar `IDs` it shows two similar items, so if I can remove the same queryString values it would prevent it from fetching similar items.

QueryString looks like this `Product?id=1&id=1` then renders the item twice.

Getting the values from `textarea`

```
var getVal = $('textarea.input_' + inputSearch.name).val();
if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
   let inputValues = getVal
      .split("\n") // allows multiple search using new line
      .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
      .join("&" + inputSearch.name + "=");
      // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
      query = query + inputSearch.name + "=" + inputValues + "&";
}
```

Comment: What is inside the textarea ?

Comment: Id numbers (e.g id=1)

Comment: Thus user can write "**id=12id=48waow**" ?

Comment: @Weedoze they can but that won't show anything but an error, the question is only concern about duplicate values like `id=1&id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your use of `array.prototype.filter()` to achieve uniqueness before joining:

```
var getVal = $('textarea.input_' + inputSearch.name).val();
if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
   let inputValues = getVal
      .split("\n") // allows multiple search using new line
      .filter(function (elem, index, self) {
        return elem !== "" && index == self.indexOf(elem)
       })
      .join("&" + inputSearch.name + "=");

  // then add it to the overall query string for all searches
  query = query + inputSearch.name + "=" + inputValues + "&";
}
```

Comment: It's not removing duplicate values

Comment: Of course you'll have to use the unique values for joining, not the original - fixed that in the answer. There's also a more elegant way that makes use of `array.filter()` instead, I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Updated the code in the answer to extend the filtering before the join.

Comment: the above answer to extend filter, `self.indexOf()` is not a function it says.

Comment: Yup, there was an argument missing, but I already corrected that with an edit.

Comment: yep found that right after I post my reply, both codes works but which one is more efficient. Extending the filter looks cleaner as it doesn't need to iterate though the values.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/filter-vs-helperarray/1 - in Chrome, the difference is not that huge for me, but in Firefox, filter() is about three times faster. Definitely go for using filter() - I'm going to remove the original approach from my answer.

Comment: Amazing, thanks :) definitely sticking with `.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

instead of concatenating some values you can use something like map collection in javascript

- map is a data structure that every key matching to specific value and if two times for a specific key, any value is set previous value always will be overridden

for map collection implementation in js take a look on following link

http://www.collectionsjs.com/map

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? It uses some data structures that are new and not fully compatible. But it works

```
var query='';
var parameters = new Set();
var getVal = "1\n2\n3";
if (getVal != null && (getVal != "")) {
   getVal.split("\n")
      .filter(function (str) { return str !== "" })
      .map(function(str) {parameters.add(str)});
   let query = new URLSearchParams();
   for(let q of params) {
       query.append(inputSearch.name,q);
   }
   query.toString();
}
```